# Reducing numba @jitclass compilation time (with caching?)

Tags: python, numba

I'm using `numba`'s `@jitclass` and I want to reduce the compilation time.

For example (my actual class is much bigger):

```
@jitclass
class State:
    a: int
    b: int

    def __init__(self):
        a = 0
        b = 0

    def update(self, x: int):
        self.a += x
        self.b -= x
```

I tried adding the `cache` parameter to `@jitclass`, but it seems that it isn't supported.

```
@jitclass(cache=True)
class State:
    ...
```

I also tried to change my class just to hold data, and compile all methods with `@njit` with `cache`:

```
@jitclass
class State:
    a: int
    b: int

    def __init__(self):
        a = 0
        b = 0

@njit(cache=True)
def update(state: State, x: int):
    state.a += x
    state.b -= x
```

But this seems to make compilation time even worse. My guess is that because `State` isn't cached it compiles each time, and then the dependent functions requires compilation.

Is there any solution that reduces this compilation time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a **known opened issue** and it looks like this will not be solved soon (since the problem has been reported since at least 6 years ago). You can get information about this in the following issues: [#1](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/6522), [#2](https://github.com/hgrecco/numbakit-ode/issues/5), [#3](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/1681). `jitclass` cannot be currently safely cached across interpreter restarts and this is a pretty deep issue. To quote one developer:

> Note that if this pickling did work, then the cached bytecode would be *invalid across interpreter restarts*, as it contains a *hard-coded memory address* of where the type used to live.

Using structrefs seems to be a workaround (though not great). Restructuring the code so not to use jitclass if possible is a better option. Note that jitclass and structref are *experimental* features so far.